# Can I use Prism 5 with .NET 4.6.2

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-5, .net-4.6.2

I use Visual Studio 2013 and have upgraded a WPF solution from .NET 4.5.1 to 4.6.2.

I was using the PRISM 5 libraries, but I seem to be getting some build errors relating to classes using Prism after the upgrade, along the lines of :

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Should Prism 5 build and run with .NET 4.6.2?  Links like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) suggest Prism 5 might only support 4.5.x, but a lot of google has got me nowhere conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Prism 5 has been deprecated and is no longer supported you should be able to use it in an application that targets .NET Framework 4.6.2 as the latter is a backward-compatible in-place update to the .NET Framework 4 through 4.6.1.

Create a new WPF application project in Visual Studio, right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Manage NuGet Packages" and then click on the "Online" item in the pane of the left, search for "Prism" and install the "Prism (Deprecated)" package. This should download and reference the Prism 5 assemblies and you should be able to build the application afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, removing and re-adding the references worked ... eventually.